# Iterate through multiple collections in the same "for" loop?

Tags: java, syntax, for-loop, iterator

I wonder if there's such a way to iterate thru multiple collections with the extended for each loop in java.

So something like:

```
for (Object element : collection1, collection2, ....)
         // do something ...
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the semantics of that? All of collection1, then collection2? Or first of all collections, then second of all collections...

Comment: @user1291492 That is a syntax error, of course. So it would have to be "something different".

Comment: Right, that obviously doesn't work. But I'm just wondering if there're some "nice" ways to do the similar things without actually changing the original collections.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do exactly this with [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Iterables.concat()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable...%29):

```
for (Foo element : Iterables.concat(collection1, collection2)) {
    foo.frob();
}
```

Comment: It is surprising that Java does not provide a CompositeCollection, or something like this.

Comment: @Raedwald it pretty much does, with Streams.

Answer (score 3):

```
Collection<Foo> collection1 = ...
Collection<Foo> collection2 = ...
Collection<Foo> collection3 = ...
...

Collection<Foo> all = ...
all.addAll(collection1);
all.addAll(collection2);
all.addAll(collection3);
...

for(Foo element : all)
{

}
```

Comment: This's doing a copy. (which is not what I'd like because that'd increase memory usage)

Answer (score 3):

With plain Java 8 and without any additional libraries:

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> compositeIterable(Collection<? extends T>... collections)
{
    Stream<T> compositeStream = Stream.of(collections).flatMap(c-> c.stream());
    return compositeStream::iterator;
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
for (Foo element : MyClass.compositeIterable(collection1, collection2)) {
    foo.frob();
}
```