# How to use foreach between 2 entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hello I have 2 entity

One is User and   the other one is UserRight. What I want to do basicly; I want to make a list called : userRightViewList and after creating list,  I want to make a for each statetement for my entiy called "User". And make another foreach statement for "userRight" and userRight for statement needs to take loginName entity for User my entites below;

User;

```
private String loginName;
    private String password;
    private char gender;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private Date createAt;
    private Character isLocked;
    private Character isBanned;
    private String email;
    private String gsm;
    private String companyCode;
    private String isActive;
```

UserRight;

```
private String accessRightCode;
    private String companyCode;
    private String isActive;
    private String loginName;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String vendorId;
```

Comment: What is keeping you from doing so?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949020/iterate-through-multiple-collections-in-the-same-for-loop

Comment: If you use User and UserRight as key value pair, then this will solve issue I think

Answer (score 2):

Edit your User class to add a field such as

```
private List<UserRight> userRight
```

I dont know what you are triying to do, but I think you're modeling it in the wrong way.

Comment: I want to write a service

Comment: I can guess you can write a service. What I don't understand is why you are modeling your entities like that. User and UserRight must have some kind of relationship. As you post, you use the String "loginName" as the attribute to connect each other, with is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Are you using an ORM (Hibernate) or similar? Please specify your environment so we can help you better.